# How do I access the Column and Row values of a cell I select in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working with a GridView that looks like an excel spreadsheet. I need to select a cell or hover over that cell and display the row and column values of that particular cell of the GridView.

My specific requirement is to hover the mouse over the gridView cells and display in a tooltip the value inside that cell, the value of its row and the value of its column.

EDIT:

The gridView represents a table that has its columns representing days and its rows representing Users. The first columns has the names of the users and the first row has the days of the month.

The following code shows the name of the user when i put my mouse over a cell. But I also need to show the day that the cell belongs to.

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.ToolTip = "User: " + (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["User"].ToString() + "Day: ";// Day needs show what day the cell belongs to
    }
}
```

I hope I could explain myself correctly.

SOLUTION:

I came up with a solution that worked for me.

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2015, 4);//Specific year
        for (int i = 1; i < days; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = i.ToString() + (e.Row.DataItem as     DataRowView)["User"].ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

This is a short version of the code that solved my problem.

Comment: I am not sure whether webforms give some guarantees about the generated html or not, so whether it is possible to easily navigate cells and rows on the client side is a moot topic. But I can propose you to use the [data-* attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) on the cell content bound to the appropriate values  . It is a lot of duplicated data sent to the client  but it will work for sure (and will be very easy to use).

Comment: Nonetheless as far as I know it usually uses `table` so you can also try to backtrack from the cell to the enclosing `tr` and `table` and then count the rows and columns(or get some header data depending on your requirements).

Comment: Post some code you have already tried.